# Cordova reference error on Ionic application with push

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, push

I attempt to include a Push service in my phonegap/ionic application, but im stuck, the case is: I follow a tutorial, and i search from anothers
tutorials, and there tutorials, show the usage of the same plugins and methods, the plugin is https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push, 
im taking the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
```

on the code

```
... 

var PushNotification = function() {
};


// Call this to register for push notifications. Content of [options] depends on whether we are working with APNS (iOS) or GCM (Android)
PushNotification.prototype.register = function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
    if (errorCallback == null) { errorCallback = function() {}}

    if (typeof errorCallback != "function")  {
        console.log("PushNotification.register failure: failure parameter not a function");
        return
    }

    if (typeof successCallback != "function") {
        console.log("PushNotification.register failure: success callback parameter must be a function");
        return
    }

    cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "PushPlugin", "register", [options]);
};

...
```

my imports on index.html file

```
...
    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>  

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/RequestsService.js"></script>
    <!-- Script for push -->    
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/PushNotification.js"></script>
...
```

there's no variable with the name **cordova** on PushNotification.js, i download a example of Push, and the PushNotification.js is exactly equals mine,
the tutorials says if cordova.js import, must be before the PushNotification.js, this is correct, i note that don't have the cordova.js file 
in the default directories of Ionic, i try tu put manually and reference it, but the error still happening, i take in mind, this cordova.js is
loaded of Ionic automatically, and the PushNotification.js has a reference of cordova visible into that javascript file, i so and a idea, someone
pass for this problem with Ionic and Phonegap and Push?

Comment: Sorry if my question looks silly but, are you trying to execute this code with your desktop browser? As cordova is injected at runtime when you execute the app on your mobile device (or an emulator), indeed, it's reported as "undefined" by our browsers.

Comment: Yes i executed in browser, you is right! thanks